# how to store an information which will be alive until the system is restarted?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to implement a feature for a product.

Requirement:
A set of information has to be stored and it has to be deleted once the system (win / linux) is restarted.

If the application crashes, the information must still be available and accessible. But if the computer loses power, or if the user restarts the computer, the information should be deleted.

***EDIT:
This program is a cross platform which runs both on windows10 and linux(CentOS). So i need to code for both platforms***

Currently i have written that information to a xml file. I need to find a way to clear that information , when the system is rebooted.

Having a script which will delete that file is not an ideal option because of the security issues around the product.

Comment: On linux? Maybe [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Comment: @Shawn Windows have shared memory as well, so it should work on Windows too (but using different functions of course).

Comment: On Linux you can store your files in /tmp. This should be deleted once the system has restarted and available until then.

Comment: a separate process whose sole purpose is to store data, maybe

Comment: Your requirement that the application must be able to tell the difference between itself crashing and a computer restart (or the computer losing power) is a tough one, and one that I think requires you to have some sentinel program on the side doing the data management. Also, with the requirement that the data must be gone if the computer experiences a sudden power loss, I think your only option is to keep the data purely in memory - in fact, depending on how strict your requirement is, you might get into trouble with virtual memory being written to disk, and thus surviving power failures.

Comment: @shawn does it not the contents of the shared memory is cleared when the processes go out of scope?

Comment: [Boost.Interprocess](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-shared-memory)

Comment: from the requirements, looks like a windows service can do the job [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services)
Not sure about *nix systems but a daemon does in *nix what services do in windows .

Comment: @AbelPandian No, not as long as it's not unlinked.

Comment: @shawn. thank you. so even if we close the application and reopen the application without restarting the computer we can still access that memory , right ?

Comment: Alternatively, can i check the system up time and find out if the system was restarted?

Comment: @AbelPandian Yup. A shared memory object can be opened many times, and is only deleted when the OS reboots or when explicitly removed with `shm_unlink()`.

Comment: @shawn thanks..according to the manual : a shared memory
       object will exist until the system is shut down, or "until all
       processes have unmapped the object" and it has been deleted with
       shm_unlink(3) .. but according to what you have said, even if the application is closed the object is not unmapped from the process, right?

Comment: a shared memory created by a daemon (launched at start up of your computer) and modified by your porgram is probably your best bet. As long as the daemon is alive your shared memory will not be erased.